# Can't import class from installed and imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.6 on windows, trying to get the py_mstr module installed so I can interact with a MicroStrategy web portal

I downloaded and installed the module by running it's "setup.py" and it appears to have properly installed it to to C:...\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages

I can import the module properly, but when I try to import a class, it returns an error

```
>>> import py_mstr
>>> from py_mstr import MstrClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from py_mstr import MstrClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'MstrClient'
```

I checked and py_mstr definitely contains the class "MstrClient"

I dug around and found that folder structure might have something to do with it, but I can't figure it out

```
Python35-32
    ...
    site-packages
        ...
        py_mstr
            __init__.py
            py_mstr.py
            _pycahce__
                __init__.cpython-36.pyc
                py_mstr.cpython-36.pyc
```

Comment: In which file is the class MstrClient defined, in py-mstr/__init__.py or in py-msgr/py_mstr.py. By the way, are the - and the _ both correct?

Comment: the folder name is supposed to be py_mstr, I just fixed it in an edit.

Comment: Ok, but still, is your class indeed defined in \_\_init\_\_.py?

Comment: Sorry, no it's defined in py_mstr.py

Comment: Then it won't be found unless \_\_init\_\_.py  imports .py_mstr.py. It's fully qualified name is actually py_mstr.py_mstr.MstrClient, not py_mstr.MstrClient.

Answer (score 0):

This package doesn't seem to support Python 3. You might be able to get it to run with 2to3, but if that doesn't work, you might have to run it on Python 2 instead.

The specific Python 3 incompatibility causing your import failure is that [`py_mstr/__init__.py`](https://github.com/infoscout/py-mstr/blob/master/py_mstr/__init__.py) uses an implicit relative import to bring in the contents of `py_mstr/py_mstr.py`:

```
from py_mstr import *
```

Python 3 interprets this as importing `*` from the `py_mstr` package, not the `py_mstr.py_mstr` submodule. There may be other incompatibilities; I didn't do a thorough inspection.

Comment: I see. I'll try it with 2.7 and see if it performs better.